# Поиск по json, как получить массив с добавленными к динамической таблице данными?

Tags: json

Сама проблема:
в результате поиска по json документу к найденной строке необходимо добавить парочку дополнительных ячеек:

1) цифру 1..99 и 2) небольшое текстовое примечание, а кнопкой "go" получить всю строку с добавленным примечанием, например:

```
    | B11 | Ручка WB11 | 39 | ФИО,тел |
```

Но получаю только пустой массив: `Array()`, 
как быть, может это реализовывается как-то не так?

p.s. json документ в упрощенном виде такой:
`[{"artikul":"A13","name":"Ручка WA13"},
.... }]`

А обработчик res.php такой:

```
    `echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";`
```

Результат на картинке
[image: Такой в итоге результат]

```js
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('#search').keyup(function(){

   var searchField = $('#search').val();
   var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");  
   $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

    var output = '<form id="formx" method="post" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">'; 
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
     if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1) || (val.artikul.search(regex) != -1)) {
      output += '<span>' + val.artikul + ' </span>';
      output += ' <span>'+ val.name +' </span>';
      output += '<span><input type="text" class="mytext"><input type="submit" value="Выбрать"></span><br />';
     }
    });  
      output += '</form>';
      $('#update').html(output); // это вывод общей таблицы
   });  
  });
 }); 

/* 
3) попытка получить из найденного массив без перезагрузки
*/
function call() {
    var msg   = $('#formx').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'res.php',
          data: msg,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
   alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
          }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="instyle" type="search" name="search" id="search" autofocus />

<div id="update">вывод поиска</div>
<div id="results">вывод полной строки</div>
```

Comment: `$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { console.log(data) ; ...` - что в консоли?

Comment: в консоли либо не так смотрю, ноничего не увидел кроме комментария о jquery 1.8.3, что там Метод getPreventDefault() является устаревшим. Для его замены используйте метод defaultPrevented.

Comment: то есть Вы в колбэк `$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {` не попадаете?

Comment: А, минуту, начинаю понимать.

Comment: честно говоря, понимаю, что моя форма должна отправлять всё в $_POST, но почему-то ничего не извлекается.

Comment: У элемента `form` нет свойства `value`, то есть `$('#formx').val();` вернет пустую строку.

Comment: а как же я добавлю свойства value ? как-то поменять json? консоль выдаёт Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, ещё 2… ]

Comment: Что Вы имели в виду отправить на сервер в функции `call`?

Comment: "Что Вы имели в виду отправить на сервер в функции call?" - думал что таким образом метод call запустит функцию, т.е. отправит переменную msg. т.е. выполнит это $('#formx').val(); Но вы правы, эта часть не работает.

Comment: В Вашей форме нет ни одного инпут-элемента с назначенным атрибутом `name`. Oна ничего на сервер не отправит. Объясните, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Результат найденных совпадений набранной цифры "1" на скриншоте на сером фоне (отображается в <div id="update">найденное</div>), вот я хотел добавить к выбранной мной из списка строке еще пару элементов - так сказать цену (1...99) и комментарий с контактами клиента, поэтому и соорудил в конце таблицы инпут с "ценой" и кн "выбрать". А вот что делать с переменной output никак не въеду. т.е. в этом месте <div id="results">вывод общей строки</div> пустой массив получился.

Comment: немного изменил: output += ' <input name="artik" value="' + val.artikul + '" />';
output += ' <input name="nam" value="'+ val.name +'" />';
output += ' <input name="cena" type="text" class="mytext">';
output += ' <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Выбрать"><br />'; теперь переменная output собрала все атрибуты name из формы как я понимаю (извините, но js только пытаюсь изучить). Но результаты такие же array{} приходит пустой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не используйте элемент `form` и кнопку `submit` там, где Вам не нужно посылать на сервер всю форму:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#update').on('click', '.choose', function(e) {
    var parentRow = $(this).closest('.row');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'res.php',
      data: {
        artik: parentRow.find('.artik').val(),
        nam: parentRow.find('.nam').val(),
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });
  });

  $('#search').keyup(function(){
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");       
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      var output = '<div id="formx">';  
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if (val.name.search(regex) != -1 || val.artikul.search(regex) != -1) {
          output += '<div class="row">';
          output += ' <input class="artik" type="text" value="' + val.artikul + '"/>';
          output += ' <input class="nam" type="text" value="'+ val.name +'"/>';
          output += ' <input class="cena mytext" type="text"/>';
          output += ' <button type="button" class="choose">Выбрать</button>';
          output += '</div>';
        }
      });       
      output += '</div>';
      $('#update').html(output); // это вывод общей таблицы
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Вот это да! мега круто! кажется начало проясняться ))) Огромное спасибо!